# How does $y[x] = a x^r$ when $y'[x] = \frac{(r y[x])}{x}$ and $y[1] = a$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

When
\begin{eqnarray*}
y'[x] &=& \frac{r y[x] }{ x } \; \;\text{and} \;\; y[1] = a \\
y[x] &=& a x^r
\end{eqnarray*}
Use derivative formulas to explain the output.

What I have so far:

We know that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
y'[x] = r y[x] = k e^{rx}
\end{eqnarray*}
So we can rewrite as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
y[x] = \frac{k e^{rx} } { x}
\end{eqnarray*}
To get the value of k:
\begin{eqnarray*}
a = \frac{k e^{r} }{ 1} \\
k = \frac{a}{e^r}
\end{eqnarray*}
So now we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{(a/(e^r)) e^{rx} } { x}
\end{eqnarray*}
But when I plug this into a derivative calculator I get a solution much different than $y[x] = a x^r$. Perhaps I am approaching this wrong. What is the correct way to approach this problem using derivative formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$
y(x)=ax^r \quad \rightarrow \quad y'(x)=rax^{r-1}=\frac{r y(x)}{x}
$$

Comment: I don't understand how you were able to equate r ax^(r-1)=(r y(x)) / x

Comment: Or where you got y(x) = a x^r

Comment: We know that $y(x)=ax^r$, so we have; $y'=rax^{r-1}=r\frac{ax^r}{x}=r\frac{y}{x}$.

Comment: Ok so then we have y'(x) = r y(x) x^(r-1). How do you get the x to the bottom?

Comment: Do you know that $x^{r-1}=x^r \cdot x^{-1}=x^r \cdot \frac{1}{x}$ ?

Comment: Ok yeah I just got it. THanks